# Use/install library inside nested iframes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I am trying to use the following library https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer/ to resize an iFrame which is positioned inside an other iFrame.

What I tried is to:

- copy the minified files of the library in a /assets/lib folder of my app.
- add a link to the minified files of the library in the header of the first iFrame:

`<script src="/assets/lib/iframeResizer.min.js"></script>`
`<script src="/assets/lib/iframeResizer.content.min.js"></script>`
`<script src="/assets/lib/index.js">`
This last index.js file only exports the 2 previous files (using export and require). -> This creates an error export is not defined, and require is not defined.

- Then, when I add an iFrame that needs to be resized, I use jQuery to insert the script that uses the library:

`var script = '<script class="iframe-resizer">iFrameResize({checkOrigin: false}, ".content-card")</script>';`

`$('.fr-iframe').contents().find("body").append(script);`

If I don't add the index.js file, I get the following message "iFrameResize is not defined"

Does anyone have an idea how I could find a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

In fact, the library supports nested iframes.
Requesting the iFrameResizer using jQuery was the best solution I found.
Thanks to this I don't have to install the library manually in the header of the iframe, which simplifies the solution.